# Mysql multiple times between in query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to show age result difference like 
age between 5 and 10 AND age between 50 and 55

I have used this query

```
$sql = "select name,age from tbl where (age BETWEEN 5 AND 10) OR (age BETWEEN 50 AND 55)";
$res = mysql_query($sql)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,age, case when age BETWEEN 5 AND 10
                      then '5-10'
                      else '50-55'
                end as age_between
from tbl 
where ( age BETWEEN 5 AND 10)  
or (age BETWEEN 50 AND 55)
```

BTW it would be better to store the birthdate. Then you don't have to set the age.